# Nested library access in Android

Tags: android

I made a library(named xyz) in Android Studio which uses volley functionality. 
I imported volley using the following command in build gradle of the library xyz:
 **compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'**

I made a new project Test where in **libs** folder contain **aar** file of **xyz library.**
And imported using command: **compile (name:'xyz-debug',ext: 'aar')**

In Main Activity of Test project I am calling function of xyz library and there are no errors whatsoever but **when I try to use any Volley function directly I'm not able to access it.**

If anyone could help me out with it, It'll be great. Thanks in advance

Comment: use .aar instead

Answer (score -1):

You might not include the aar file, but include the library project in your app's build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile project(':xyzlibrary')  // this is the key
}
```

Comment: As the library will be distributive, for security reasons, I'm not opting for the above mentioned solution. Is there any other work around? Thanks David